# Dynamic polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, oop

I need to change an object's behavior on run-time.
I have two concrete object (singleton) classes `Dog` and `Cat`, both extend from an abstract class `Animal`.
The object `animal` of `Animal` type should be changed to either `Dog` or `Cat` on runtime.
Here's the rough code of something that I am trying to accomplish:

```
abstract class Animal() {
    def sound: Unit
}

object Cat extends Animal {
    def sound: Unit = {
        print("meow")
    }
}

object Dog extends Animal {
    def sound: Unit = {
        print("bark")
    }
}

object MyProgram {
    val animal: Animal = _

    def initialize(config: Config): Unit ={
        // check the config
        if (config.getString("ANIMAL_TYPE").equals("Dog")) {
            animal = Dog
        } else {
            animal = Cat
        }

    }

    def run: Unit = {
        animal.sound
    }
}

def main(): Unit = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.praseFile(myconfigfile)
    MyProgram.initialize(config)
    MyProgram.run
}
```

Can something like this be done in Scala? If not, how can I accomplish this in Scala.

Comment: Why do you want to change the type of a variable? You can always check the type of the variable at runtime with `if` or `match`.

Comment: @jwvh : Updated my dummy sample code to demonstrate my scenario. Please take a look.

Comment: Again, the only bug in your code has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Dynamic Polymorphism. The part of your code that is about Dynamic Polymorphism has *always* worked, both in your original code and in this newly modified version. In your original version, the problem was that your were not properly initializing a local variable, in this version, the problem is that you are assigning to a `val` (effectively a constant). Neither of the two has anything to do with Dynamic Polymorphism. It looks like your *actual* problem you don't understand the difference between variable and constant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should work almost as it is, just assign something to animal.

```scala
object MyProgram {
    //First of all use some default value for animal. 
    //It will be safer to use. 
    var animal: Animal = Cat 
    // or use explicitly null if there is no sensible default value. 
    // underscore makes it less clear what will happen.
    //var animal: Animal = null 

    //I thing match is better than if/else here especially when third animal will arrive. You can assign it like that:
    def initialize(config: Config): Unit ={
        animal = (config.getString("ANIMAL_TYPE") match {
            case "Dog" => Dog
            case _ => Cat 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to initialize with Cat or Dog to make it work. Can you let me know I deal with abstract type members? I get type mismatch error. Here's the link https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/0

Comment: This is much harder problem because you have different type of arguments. You need to:  work without types (cast to `Any` and back) what is extremely error prone and it is just wrong, or resolve argument based on type. Scalafiddle on the way :).

Comment: this compiles but is not best idea: mostly due to repetition and potential `MatchError`: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/1

Comment: Here is another example that create tuple: `(Animal, soundWithApplayedParam)`. Still not best but compiles and shows one of possible ways. https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/2

Comment: Here is example with casting argument to any and back: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/5. Not best either.

Comment: Here is version with dependent types: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/7. Unfortunately MPState there cannot be case class :(.

Comment: Thank you. These all seem to be working. I am sure I can use any of them. But you keep referencing them as not an ideal solution which makes me hesitant. So, what exactly is the ideal solution for the scenario like mine in Scala? or I am just approaching it the wrong way. Most of your solutions seems to be running for me.

Comment: I hoped to find sollution that will be pleasant... but each of those has it's own problems, as you can see. Some are unsafe (It is easy to make mistake), some uses non trivial code (I hoped to use case class for `MPState` and even then dependent types could be scary for someone). I'va no more time to investigate this, sorry. Maybe later I'll find some, but not sure.

Comment: Here is my preferred way: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UQYXFFL/9. Most of the time I prefer type parameters over type members and dependent types, but to be honest I don't have much experience with dependent types.

Comment: @san and I guess this is my last word in topic. Please check last version ans say what you think, about it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with typing or dynamic polymorphism:

```
           var animal : Animal = _
               ^
On line 19: error: local variables must be initialized
```

As you can see, there is nothing wrong with the types in your program, you simply need to properly initialize your variable:

```scala
def main() : Unit = {
    var animal = if(config.getString("ANIMAL_TYPE").equals("Dog")) {
        Dog
    } else {
        Cat
    }

    // this should print either bark or meow 
    animal.sound
}
```

Note that there are a couple of non-idiomatic things in your code. A more idiomatic version would look something like this:

```scala
trait Animal {
    val sound: String
}

object Cat extends Animal {
    override val sound = "meow"
}

object Dog extends Animal {
    override val sound = "bark"
}

def main(): Unit = {
    val animal = if (config.getString("ANIMAL_TYPE").equals("Dog")) Dog else Cat

    // this should print either bark or meow 
    print(animal.sound)
}
```

- Use a `trait` instead of an `abstract class`.
- Don't use an empty constructor / initializer, just use no constructor / initializer.
- Separate input/output from computation: the printing should be done in the `main` method, not in the `Animal`.
- Use the explicit `override` modifier.
- Don't use type annotations if the type is obvious.
- Don't use curly braces around single expressions.
- Don't use `var`, always use `val`.
- `if` is an expression, don't ignore its return value.

Comment: Downvoting because those bullet points are personal opinion not part of the language, and a number of them are highly contentious.

Comment: most of advices are in fact good practices in scala, but yea... some are just opinions. Trait has it's own cost and not always is better to use it. Using `val` is preferred but there are cases where you would use vars and it is OK.  opinion about curly braces again depends on codebase and sometimes you wan't to keep them (nothing wrong with it).

Comment: @Scalway : Updated my dummy sample code to demonstrate my scenario better. Please take a look.

Comment: Even thought most of the advices are good, they are opinion based, you should explain that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `main` function incorrectly.

The `main` function should be a member of some `object`, and it should have an argument of the type `Array[String]`.

```
object SomeRandomName {
  def main(): Unit = {
    var animal: Animal = null

    // check the config
    if(config.getString("ANIMAL_TYPE").equals("Dog")) {
        animal = Dog
    } else {
        animal = Cat
    }

    // this should print either bark or meow 
    animal.sound
  }
}
```

And this code should compile and run well.

**SIDENOTE**: If you are using *Scala 3* (instead of Scala 2.x), then you don't need to make a wrapper object of the `main` function. The function can be at the top level.

Comment: Please ignore the syntactic issues with my dummy code. The dummy code I put there so that I can just explain my situation properly instead of writing in paragraphs. I have updated my sample code to better explain my situation. Please take a look.

Comment: @san: Both versions of your code work perfectly fine. They have absolutely no problem whatsoever with Dynamic Polymorphism. Both version of your code have trivial bugs, but those bugs a) have nothing to do with Dynamic Polymorphism, and b) can be trivially fixed without affecting Dynamic Polymorphism. So, considering that both code samples you posted clearly demonstrate that Scala supports Dynamic Polymorphism, and that your code uses Dynamic Polymorphism just fine, it is still very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You are asking "Can something like this be done in Scala? If not, how can I accomplish this in Scala.", but you have already posted two examples showing exactly *that* it can be done in Scala and *how* it can be done, so what *precisely* is the problem you are having with those two perfectly working examples that you posted?